# How to use TextButtonStyle.overFont?

Tags: user-interface, libgdx

I'm trying to use `overFont` and `overColor` on [TextButton](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextButton.html) so the button appearance can changes when the mouse move over.

Here's the style I defined.

```
    var buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    buttonStyle.fontColor = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    buttonStyle.disabledFontColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.4f);
    buttonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable( "button_down");
    buttonStyle.up= skin.getDrawable( "button_up");
    buttonStyle.over= skin.getDrawable( "button_over");
    buttonStyle.overFontColor = new Color(0, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1f);
    buttonStyle.font = font 
    skin.add("default", buttonStyle);
```

The button is created as follows:

```
    var startGameButton = new TextButton("Start game", skin);
    startGameButton.x = buttonX;
    startGameButton.y = currentY;
    startGameButton.width = BUTTON_WIDTH;
    startGameButton.height = BUTTON_HEIGHT;
    stage.addActor(startGameButton);
    /*startGameButton.addListener ([ Event e |
        Gdx.app.log ("App", "Start game") ;
        return true ;
    ])*/
    startGameButton.addListener (new ChangeListener () {

        override changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            Gdx.app.log ("App", "Start game") ;
        }

    })
```

While the down and up state are properly taken into account, the over properties are not used: the button doesn't change when the mouse enters the button area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buttonStyle.fontOverColor = Color.BLUE;` works fine for me,
try to pass to your TextButton constructor not skin, but buttonStyle,
in TextButton there is such constructor

```
public TextButton (String text, TextButtonStyle style)
```

It's difficult to say something else, because code not looks like real working code, I mean `var` keyword or this code is not correct (there is no public variables x, y, width, height):

```
startGameButton.x = buttonX;
startGameButton.y = currentY; 
startGameButton.width = BUTTON_WIDTH;
startGameButton.height = BUTTON_HEIGHT;
```

If changing constructor will not help you, please post your real code.

Comment: Well, the code is not Java :) I'm playing with xtend those days.

Comment: For some reason, passing the skin was the issue. I'm not sure why. Could this be a bug?

Comment: oh ok, I have never heard about xtend, thanks for experience :) I don't know if this is a bug. I have never done this through skin :) Happy to help